# Xamarin.Forms with Shell: is there a way to specify a icon's color for active tab only?

Tags: xamarin.forms, fonts, tabbar, xamarin.shell

I'm working on a **Xamarin.Forms** app based on **Shell**, and I'm using **font icons** as icons for the `TabBar`:

```
<TabBar>
    <ShellContent Title="Home" Route="HomePage" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:HomePage}">
        <ShellContent.Icon>
            <FontImageSource Glyph="{StaticResource FasIconHome}" FontFamily="FontAwesomeSolid" />
        </ShellContent.Icon>
    </ShellContent>
</TabBar>
```

I would like to specify a color only for the **active tab**, but **only for the icon**, not for the text, as we can see on Airbnb:
[image: Airbnb screenshot]

I didn't found any option in the Shell settings:

```
<Setter Property="Shell.BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="Shell.ForegroundColor" Value="Black" />
<Setter Property="Shell.TitleColor" Value="Black" />
<Setter Property="Shell.DisabledColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-300}" />
<Setter Property="Shell.UnselectedColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-300}" />
<Setter Property="Shell.TabBarBackgroundColor" Value="White" />
<Setter Property="Shell.TabBarForegroundColor" Value="{StaticResource Gray-300}"/>
<Setter Property="Shell.TabBarUnselectedColor" Value="#95000000" />
<Setter Property="Shell.TabBarTitleColor" Value="Black" />
```

***Is it possible?***

Comment: Hi, we can use ShellRenderer to have a try, however there are some problems when doing that. If I have solved that will share the answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case , you used **FontImageSource** to set the icon of tab item . However ,  if you want to set the color of a specific item icon , you need to download the icon with different color in advance and put the icon in both of native platform (**Asset** in iOS and **Drawable** in Android) . And set it by using Custom Renderer

#### in iOS

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using xxx;
using xxx.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(ShellCustomRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class ShellCustomRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        protected override IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker CreateTabBarAppearanceTracker()
        {
            return new TabBarAppearance();
        }

    }

    public class TabBarAppearance : IShellTabBarAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void ResetAppearance(UITabBarController controller)
        {
            

        }
      
        public void SetAppearance(UITabBarController controller, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            UITabBar myTabBar = controller.TabBar;

            if (myTabBar.Items != null)
            {
                var item = myTabBar.Items[0];

                //default icon
                item.Image = UIImage.FromBundle("xxx.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);

                //selected icon
                item.SelectedImage = UIImage.FromBundle("xxx.png").ImageWithRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.AlwaysOriginal);
            }
        }

        

        public void UpdateLayout(UITabBarController controller)
        {
        }
    }   

}
```

#### in Android

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppShell), typeof(ShellCustomRenderer ))]
namespace xxx.Droid
{
    public class ShellCustomRenderer : ShellRenderer
    {
        public MyShellRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker CreateBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker(ShellItem shellItem)
        {
            return new CustomBottomNavAppearance();
        }
    }

    public class CustomBottomNavAppearance : IShellBottomNavViewAppearanceTracker
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {

        }

        public void ResetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView)
        {

        }

        public void SetAppearance(BottomNavigationView bottomView, ShellAppearance appearance)
        {
            bottomView.ItemIconTintList = null;
            IMenu myMenu = bottomView.Menu;

            IMenuItem myItemOne = myMenu.GetItem(0);

            if (myItemOne.IsChecked)
            {
                myItemOne.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.xxx); // selected icon
            }
            else
            {
                myItemOne.SetIcon(Resource.Drawable.xxx); //default icon
            }

         

        }
    }
}
```